# How to implement this stuff like tooltip in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a requirement to create below component by CSS or Javascript.
[image]

I will receive an array like `[{'label':'status1'}, {'label':'status2'}, {'label':'status3'}, {'label':'status4'}, {'label':'status5'},{'label':'status6'}].`

And it also support support the highlight red like below.
[image] 
In this case, it will receive an array like `[{'label':'status1', 'priority': 'high'}, {'label':'status2'}, {'label':'status3'}, {'label':'status4'}, {'label':'status5'},{'label':'status6'}].`

It also support the click and hover event like below.
[image]

Actually I mainly does not understand how to implement the shape like below small one.
[image]

Comment: Why javascript tag? Google css triangle.

Comment: This may help you https://codepen.io/ryanmcnz/pen/JDLhu

Comment: And another: http://www.cssarrowplease.com/   Googling "css triangle box" results in a lot of good answers. As far as a tooltip, a lot of CSS frameworks like Bootstrap make that easy. There are probably many npm packages too.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, The solution only for shape and hover effects.

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/o6r4z8ah/)

```
<ul class="status">
  <li><a href=""><span>#</span>Status 1</a></li>
  <li><a href=""><span>#</span>Status 2</a></li>
  <li><a href=""><span>#</span>Status 3</a></li>
  <li><a href=""><span>#</span>Status 4</a></li>
  <li><a href=""><span>#</span>Status 5</a></li>
  <li><a href=""><span>#</span>Status 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks very much.

Comment: Hi, Kumar. I looked over your code for about one year, but I can not totally understand it.
Since when I inspected the html element in chrome, I found the '.status li a:before' and '.status li a:after' is the same place, why? and how was the bubble like stuff(triangle)  produced? it's from css border property? thanks.

Comment: Hi Liam, CSS pseudo `:before` and `:after` can generate content in CSS without HTML elements. As these, both are `position: absolute` so I can place where ever I want. About css triangle [read this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/). Triangle is possible with border properties. `:after` is used for border on the triangle.

Answer (score 1):

To create boxes with arraows there are a couple of solutions: SVG, CSS3 or image (the worst). See above comments for CC3 examples.

Using the `:hover` in CSS , it is possible to make it change color in CSS.

To make it select-able, add a click event listener on each box that changes the component state. Use that state in the `render` to add or not a class like `.selected`. Then again in CSS give this class some other colors

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution for that shape using pseudo element, position and transform.

```css
.container {
  font-size: 0;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 13px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 75px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background: white;
}

.box:not(:last-of-type) {
  border-right: none;
}

.box:not(:last-of-type):after {
    content: '';
    background: inherit;
    height: 8px;
    width: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 101%;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    border-top: 3px solid black;
    border-right: 3px solid black;
    transform: rotateZ(45deg) translate(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <span>#</span>
    <span>Status 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <span>#</span>
    <span>Status 2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <span>#</span>
    <span>Status 3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```